# How do you set the default tab image for a Facebook app?

Tags: image, facebook-apps, facebook-page

In the new Facebook page format with Timeline, our App Tab is now in the top section and by default uses the App's logo.

If someone installs the tab they can upload their own 111x74 "Custom Tab Image". But we would like to change the default 111x74 image used for our App, as the App logo is not the best image for the Page Tab.

How do you define the default "Tab Image" without having to change the App logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time a default 111x74 image cannot be set.  Let's hope that Facebook adds this functionality soon.

Currently the default image is just the 75x75 app logo.

**Update on 4/12**

Facebook just added the functionality for developers to set a default image.  [Here is the post in the Developer Blog.][1]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. It would be great if we could specify the image based on the settings I've stored for the page in my app...

Comment: Hi guys, I tried to change the image with a new icon for an app but the problem is that when adding the app to new pages the tab is still created with the old image. Is it working for you?